# Pagination not showing using Admin-LTE 3 with DataTables in Laravel Mix

Tags: laravel, datatables, adminlte

I'm trying to use the DataTables plugin that's included in Admin-LTE 3 (Bootstrap 4) but it seems that the plugin is not found.

The page currently looks like:

[image: Current view]

But I want it to look as:

[image]

Everything else looks "ok" and as it should, for example clicking on the pages or sorting but the styles are bot being substituted for Bootstrap 4.

So it appears that the bootstrap.datatables is never added to the main plugin:

Currently my webpack.mix.js looks like:

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/assets/js')
  .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/assets/css')
  .version();
```

And inside app.js it has:

```
// Import and set jQuery
global.$ = global.jQuery = require('jquery');
// Import bootstrap
require('bootstrap');
// Import datatables
require('admin-lte/plugins/datatables/jquery.dataTables');
require('admin-lte/plugins/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap4');
// Import admin-lte-3
require('admin-lte');
```

and on app.scss I have:

```
// Import Google Font: Source Sans Pro
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,400i,700');
// Import datatatables
@import '~admin-lte/plugins/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap4';
// Import admin-lte-3
@import '~admin-lte/dist/css/adminlte.css';
```

Any ideas?

Comment: why do you using from style in your script `require('admin-lte/plugins/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap4.css');
` this is wrong

Comment: Thanks, I changed it, sadly this didn't fixed the problem

Comment: I kind of fix the problem... just don't use the admin-lte plugins with Laravel mix and use the proper libraries: https://datatables.net/download/npm

Answer (score 1):

You have the file paths wrong.

In order to import the DataTables plugin correctly, you should have:

```
// JS
require("admin-lte/plugins/datatables/jquery.dataTables");
require("admin-lte/plugins/datatables-bs4/js/dataTables.bootstrap4");
```

```
// CSS
@import "~admin-lte/plugins/datatables-bs4/css/dataTables.bootstrap4";
```

Answer (score 0):

*Remove this*

`require('admin-lte/plugins/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap4.css');`

*from your `app.js`*

*then add the file in your style `resources/scss/app.scss` like this*

`@import '~admin-lte/plugins/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap4';`

Comment: Thanks, I changed it, sadly this didn't fixed the problem, I think that the dataTables.bootstrap4.js is not recognizing the jQuery plugin.